# How to import an image when the resolution is less than 700px?

Tags: html, css

I want to import a picture ONLY when the screen resolution is > 700px

```
 HTML:

 <picture>       
    <img id="logo_mobile">
    <!-- I try too -->

    <source srcset="logomobile.jpg" media="(min-width: 700px)"
 </picture>

 CSS:

 #logo_mobile {
         background-image: url('logomobile.jpg');
  }
```

Both not working.

Comment: Your question says "picture" but the HTML says "figure"; are you looking for "img"?

Comment: I wrote it wrong. So <picture>. Is not working. Just call directly and nothing happens.

Comment: What if you replace "picture" with "img"?

Comment: Please, reread my question.

Comment: There are errors in your HTML. The `source` element is missing its `>` and the `img` is missing its `src` attribute. Also, the question title says "less than 700 px" but the first line says "> 700px", so which is it? And your question asks about the _screen_ resolution, while the media in the `source` is about the window size.

Comment: By the way, the `picture` element is not supported by all browsers yet. Which browsers are you targeting?

Comment: Googe Chrome. Version 47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question properly, you want to display an element (img, whatever) only when the screen resolution is bigger than 700px e.g.

I suggest you just use:

HTML:

```
<img src="logo_mobile.gif" class="big_v_only"/>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 699px) {
   .big_v_only {
      display:none;
   }
}
```

This will hide the .big_v_only class elements, when device width < 700

Comment: BTW. That's just the easiest way to make your projects mobile-friendly with css. Notice that you can easily add more element in the _@media only screen and (maniana maniana)_{}, so they look different (or disappear, or became visible) in low-resolution devices (like mobile devices). You can also create more 'versions' of your css, for various resolution, just replacing '699px' with any other value.